# how could I add a post var as a param of a template tag in magento?

Tags: templates, magento, parameters

Inside the template account_new_confirmation, which is the template of the confirmation mail the user receives after he creates a new account, I need to add a param inside the tag

```
{{store url="customer/account/confirm/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.confirmation _query_back_url=$back_url _query_myparam="TEST"}}
```

this is working for a string producing the following link to be written inside the confirmation mail as expected:

```
http://baseurl/customer/account/confirm/?id=12345&key=donkey&back_url=monkey&myparam=TEST
```

but I cannot figure out how to replace the string TEST with the value of a param I have in request post.
I mean the user reach this point after having filled a form sent with POST action. Inside this form I have a checkbox named FOO and I need to add its value (true or false) to _query_myparam on my example above.
I tried with

```
_query_param=$foo
```

and with

```
_query_param=$this->getRequest()->getPost('foo')
```

but they both were too easy to work.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself :D

You have to change the method `sendNewAccountEmail` of the class `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` which you can find in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`

You need to add new variables available inside the template inside:

```
array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl)
```

So for your need this would be changed in:

```
array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl, 'foo' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('foo'))
```

Then you can add this variable to the template param as

```
{{store url="customer/account/confirm/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.confirmation _query_back_url=$back_url _query_myparam=$foo}}
```

This will produce the following link:

```
http://baseurl/customer/account/confirm/?id=12345&key=donkey&back_url=monkey&myparam=on
```

when checkbox FOO is checked.

Thanks